# get two person names in a single query from the same table in one row

Tags: php, mysql

**Description :**

I have a table which has a coloumn name 'student_name'.

Now each student has a registration id through which all the actions in the website take place.

Now I am at a point where if one student of same class (as class mate) posts something then the other class mate gets notified ... every thing is working fine but there is a performance issue right now I am doing this

**SQL and PHP**

```
$pn = $f_notif['notif_by'];
$rn = $f_notif['notif_of'];
$sql_1 = mysql_query("select stname from students where stregno = '$pn'");
$sql_2 = mysql_query("select stname from students where stregno = '$rn'");
```

Now `$sql_1` holds the name of the poster student and `$sql_2` holds the name of the 2nd student who gets notified.

Notice that I am making 2 requests to get the names of these two students which being fetched from different queries require `mysql_fetch_array()` to run two times aswell

**What I want :**

what I want is to some how get the two names in 1 sql query so that I am not making 2 simultaneous requests to the server.

Any one ?? I am stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IN` :

```
SELECT stregno, stname FROM students WHERE stregno IN ('$pn', '$rn')
```

Or, a `OR` clause :

```
SELECT stregno, stname FROM students WHERE (stregno = '$pn' OR stregno = '$rn')
```

Comment: I am getting the result in two rows but it'll do the job.. Yes the 'IN' clause why didn't I think of that .. thanks that was quick :)

Comment: stregno would also be required in the fields returned by the query so he can identify which user is which so he will get 2 arrays like: `'stname' => 'yyy', 'stregno' => 'the_value_from_rn'` and `'stname' => 'zzz', 'stregno' => 'the_value_from_pn'`

Comment: @Rks Rock if this answer provided the answer you required, please award it :D